# If an international bank has branches in two countries, can I bank transfer between them?

Tags: international-transfer, wire-transfer

I currently use wire transfers to move money from the US to the country in Europe that I live in now.  The problem with this is that it's a hassle (I have to call the bank, verify I give the correct numbers, and there's a fee).

If a bank that's say, based in England, has branches in the US and also my current country, can I send money from my US bank to it, and withdraw it from the branch here (or use an ATM)?

My problem is that I regularly transfer money and pay fees for wire transfers and Western Union.  Also I'll probably need to transfer a large amount at some point to buy property, and that would require several (dozens?) of wire transfers with associated phone calls and fees for each.

Comment: Why would you require more than one wire transfer for a large amount of money. Transfers can move millions if not trillions of dollars in one message.

Comment: I won't name specifics but I'd suggest looking into alternatives to wire transfers, they can be significantly cheaper

Comment: Could you clarify what is your problem? Answering your question, it doesn't matter at all if the bank is international or not, the only thing that matters, is they belong to SWIFT. And no, you don't have to call your bank to 'verify' the numbers. There's something wrong in whatever you do.

Comment: @DanubianSailor: Of course it may make a difference if the bank is international. Banks typically charge for making international SWIFT transfers, but sometimes transfers within the same bank are free (or cheaper) - whether that is true for international transfers is the whole point of the question. And yes, when you call the bank to set up a transfer, you do need to verify that you give them the correct numbers, otherwise there is a risk that the transfer will go to the wrong account, in which case you may lose it.)

Comment: @psmears it's obvious you need to double check if the account number is correct, but at least IBANs have built-in validation. But I hear first time you are required to call the bank to manually verify the numbers... 
Fees are another pair of shoes, but it has nothing to do with being able to do a transfer or not...

Comment: @DanubianSailor: The question explicitly asks about fees. The reason they're asking about international banks is that they're hoping that a transfer within the same bank (even an international transfer) will be free/cheaper. I don't know whether that's true (not something I've tried), but it seems a legitimate thing to ask :)

Comment: @DanubianSailor re. callling, my bank requires that I call them to initiate an international wire transfer.  It's about 15 minutes on the phone going over "why do you want to do this", "could you verify those numbers", "what's the destination bank address".  I'd rather not do that frequently.

Comment: @HorseHair so your *real* problem is that your bank doesn't have a decent online banking? Or only international transfers are so screwed up? In both cases, it screams for changing your bank.

Comment: @DanubianSailor My bank is USAA, a phenomenal bank.

Comment: There are schemes you can use to get around foreign exchange fees. One obvious one is to just use a credit card that doesn't have exchange fees. Another more complicated one is to buy securities in one market and sell in the other.

Comment: @DanubianSailor when I was in a similar situation, I was told by my (Canadian) bank that I couldn't send a wire transfer without setting foot in a bank due to anti-money laundering/scam laws (though not sure how true that is). So it could be worse, and it's not necessarily an issue with a particular bank but the country itself. North American consumer banking is generally terrible compared to Europe and elsewhere

Comment: Why would you doubt that? Have you met a problem, or is this purely theoretical? Either way, you should be able to make transfers between any banks, which means the bank having branches in different countries should at worst make transfers easier. Is that not obvious?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin wire transfers are more expensive than bank transfers.  Everyone else who's answered here seems to get the point.

Comment: @HorseHair Sorry and having sent far too much cash internationally, I never heard  of a difference between "bank…" and "wire…" transfers and so what?

If an international bank has branches in two countries, why might you not be able to make bank transfers between them?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin you may want to read the answers here and/or do some googling.

Comment: @HorseHair You might want to read the answers here and/or do some Googling. Until you do, the obvious Answer to the OQ here, "If an international bank has branches in two countries, can I bank transfer between them?" remains "Yes, of course. Why would you doubt that?"

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I'm guessing you're from the UK or EU, or somewhere else with a well-developed electronic interbank network, so take it for granted that you can just enter an account number into an online bank and have the bank sort out the details of getting the funds transferred. As I understand it, that's just not the case in the US, even for *domestic* transfers. The fact that entire businesses exist just for facilitating international "wire transfers" should be reason enough to question your assumptions of "yes, of course".

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks for that clarification. Long before it came here to the UK, my first experience of a "modern" electronic interbank network was the real-time gross transfer in Zimbabwe, ironically otherwise so "well-developed" that in a month's travel, I never saw an ATM without a 24-hour armed guard. VISA ATMs let me draw cash from my London bank in tiny remote settlements. Isn't half the reason for wire transfer specialists that the recipients don't use banks?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin It may be _half_ the reason, but it is definitely not the only use case. See [Wise.com's product description](https://wise.com/gb/send-money/) for instance: step 3 is "Fill in the details of your recipient’s bank account", step 5 is "Send your money with a bank transfer, or a debit or credit card". They don't even list cash in or cash out as options, although they may have a different product for that.

Comment: Depending on the sum and frequency of your transfers, any bank will need to make sure you're not laundering money, committing fraud, evading taxes or funding terrorism. Most banks are required by the authorities to make inquiries to verify the legitimacy of transfers (especially international transfers with high amounts). So while you may avoid some fees and maybe make the questioning more pleasant, you will not get around it.

Answer (score 31):

This isn't something that's automatically offered just by virtue of the bank having branches in two countries. You'd need to ask the specific bank what facilities they offer.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that the branches of (say) Barclays in the US are not actually branches of the same company as Barclays in the UK.  (Both banks are wholly-owned subsidiaries of a holding company, but they are different banks with different banking licenses.)

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica same with ING in Poland and Netherlands. I'm a client of Polish ING, and Netherlands one was able to recognize me as a client, offer me coffee and cookies... And they had no access to help me unlock my debit card. They offered me a free phone call to Polish "branch" but because they work on different licenses, that was all they could do.

Comment: Given the scope of OP's question, almost certainly not. With transfers in the region of the value of a house, we will almost certainly be hitting AML/KYC limits.

Answer (score 10):

HSBC Premier allows direct international transfer free of charge.
You only need to open an account in each country. Their online tool is called *Global View*.

Comment: It's certainly possible to transfer between different accounts (although the OP is a bit vague about what exactly they're doing). The difficulty may be in opening a new account and providing acceptable documents to do so - not always trivial. But certainly this explains how it can be done.

Comment: Yes agree. I believe to open an account in a foreign country you might need more than just a tourist visa.

Answer (score 5):

Not without creating another local account at the same bank in England - KYC (know your customer) norms are pretty strict internationally, and each country has their own banking and tax regulations which every bank has to comply with.

Once you create a local account, you should be able to do inter-branch international transfers with ease. However, *it doesn't necessarily mean that this will be faster or cheaper*. For example, Smaller banks actually use the services of larger banks to do international transfers. This can result in higher fees and slower transfer speeds too. And most banks also charge a currency conversion fees that are often higher.

But all this depends on your bank and only they can clearly tell you how much fees they'll charge and how much time the transfers will take.

Since you are buying a property, I'd advise you to create a local bank account and seek advise from the bank. You will also benefit from their advise on local banking regulations and tax laws that you should be aware of. While banking with the same bank is often convenient, check out competing local banks too as they may offer better services and deals (like reduced fees) to have you as a customer.

**Note**: International debit cards often allow you to withdraw currency in any country through their partner networks (often Maastercard or Visa). But obviously the fees are higher.

**Tip**: One thing we indians abroad often do is a "swap transfer" - basically we find another indian in the foreign country where we work, and pay that person the amount we want to transfer in the local foreign currency, and they then transfer the same amount in indian currency to our local indian bank account from their local indian account. (Or vice versa). So both parties save on the transfer fees and get better deal on the currency conversion without any additional fees. Ofcourse, you have to trust the person to not cheat you. And you also have to be mindful of the tax laws - we create documentation to show it as a personal loan, in case, on rare occasion we are questioned about the nature of such transfers by the tax authorities. This is legal in India (see my comment below for more details).

Comment: the "trust" in the "swap transfer" is a big thing ! There is an app doing that for you, which is big enough that you can trust. See my answer

Comment: This is great, thank you

Comment: "we create documentation to show it as a personal loan" - that sounds like fraud, because it's a currency exchange, not a personal loan. So you are not being mindful of the laws - you are being mindful of getting caught.

Comment: @user253751 - No, this is perfectly legal in India. According to indian laws, if someone gives you a large sum of money, the tax authority treats it as a gift and will tax you for it unless you can prove that it wasn't a gift. In our case, we are doing a simple exchange of currency. You can indeed show it as that too, but then you and the other person have to waste time to show them you didn't make any profits during the currency exchange as the profits are indeed taxable. In our case, we are doing a simple swap on a "no profit, no loss basis", and so it is simpler to show it as a loan.

Comment: "Once you create a local account, you should be able to do inter-branch international transfers with ease. " <-- This is plain false. You should really have at least some valid examples in mind before postulating general trends.

Comment: @sfxedit but then it is fraud, and they can put you in jail, even if you didn't make a profit.

Comment: @Argyll What is false? It is easier to do international transfers between branches of the bank as you are a customer whose id can be easily verified. It doesn't however mean there will be less red tape, or that the process will be faster or cheapre (which I have mentioned). Not sure I understood your point. (And I am saying this based on my own international experience).

Comment: @user253751 Yes, technically, misreporting it is illegal. I have an accountant who manages my tax, and I follow his advise. The tax authority in India is incredibly bureaucratic, and so it is common to use shortcuts like these to circumvent them and make our jobs easier. The IT department is also forgiving of such things, as they can happen by mistaes too, and they'd rather spend their time chasing after tax evasions than minor issues like these where no tax needs to be paid.

Comment: @sfxedit: I quoted your statement before I said which is false. Your guidance of "create a local account and you will be able to do bank transfer between that and your current account" is not true. It's not an advice people can follow. e.g. HSBC has branches all over the place. Try it. And it will be in vein. So what's the point of that recommendation?

Comment: @Argyll The point is better customer service - banks like international clients as they often are HNI and thus provide better services to them (like home banking or phone banking). A big issue with banks is KYC (know your customer) because that's where they face the most scrutiny by the regulators. Banking within same banks helps with that as the bank manager can call up your branch in another country to enquire about you to their satisfaction. That is what I meant *... with ease* and highlighted that it wouldn't mean the actual international transfers would be necessarily faster or cheaper.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is *almost* possible, but only with one bank: Wise.

---

EDIT: Here below I explain how I understand Wise works because people around me who didn't know about it have suggested similar ideas for international transfers. I believe you allude to the same scheme of 1 bank in multiple countries, and [sfxedit's answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/153312/63990) also suggests a similar scheme, but with acquaintances rather than a neutral 3rd party.

So the reason to explain it is because **yes, it can be that simple**.

And yes, this reads like an ad because I am enthusiastic to share about it. It has saved me many times from international transfer fees, and I feel the least I can do is to raise awareness.

Furthermore, I would really like Wise and other neo-banks<sup>1</sup> to succeed because I feel the traditional banking has deliberately not pushed new technology to clients in order to keep them paying ; meanwhile, while they have optimised their IT, reduced personnel, and automatised most of the operations.

<sup>1 See [this article on Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/advisor/banking/what-is-a-neobank/) about what is a neo-bank. It doesn't have to have branches. Yes, Revolut, N24, Neon and others are neo-banks.</sup>

---

Wise, formerly TransferWise, has set up exactly this back in ~2014, in order to lower fees of sending money across countries. They had accounts with big banks in multiple countries, but this was transparent to the end users. In turn, end users use the Wise app to tell the bank about the transfer: amount, destination, currency, etc. Then they are given an account in their local country (e.g. US in your case), and a reference that tracks the transfer. Users send the money to this account, mentioning the reference. Upon receival, Wise retains a small fee (much smaller than regular banks), and sends money from their foreign account to the user's destination (e.g. Europe in your case).

Now they also offer an "international" card. You can charge it with money in your currency of choice, and then pay and withdraw money in any currency in any country. You can even pay online, avoiding costly conversion fees (there still are some, but are way smaller and the exchange rate is fair).

I am not affiliated with Wise, but I've been a happy cross-country user of them since 2015 and I think they provide a really good service.

---

<sup>P.S. Wise also has a referral scheme: if you join with a referral link, your first transfer is completely free, and the person referring you may get ~€40. "May get", because they only get it when accumulating 3 invites</sup>

Comment: I don't think Wise are actually a bank. Revolut are but neither really has "branches".

Comment: As noted by GS, Wise is not actually a bank, but as well as opening an international account with Wise, you can transfer dollars from your own bank in the US to Wise who well then instantly transfer the sterling to your bank account in the UK (other country/currency combinations work too).  There are a number of other similar services.

Comment: This answer reads like an advertisement.

Comment: Banks and services like Revolut and Wise (and many others, depending on which region of the world you care about) are great... but this answer is inaccurate for claiming Wise is unique and reading like an ad for Wise.

Comment: Downvote. I use Wise myself and it is definitely a good solution for OP, but the phrasing of the answer is a bit too enthusiastic and ad-like. Also there is no need to mention the referral feature, even if it's just a footnote.

Comment: I came here to post exactly the same recommendation. I have been using Wise for two years now to transfer between GBP, EUR, and HUF, painlessly and almost for free. @bracco23, there is nothing wrong with enthusiasm!

Comment: I think you mean "opaque to users", if you're trying to say that it's something the users aren't made aware of

Comment: Nonsense. You can transfer money between virtually any bank belonging to SWIFT. As long as your country wasn't kicked out of SWIFT or otherwise put on sanction list.

Comment: Thank you everyone who highlighted the ad-like formulation of my answer. I added an edit to explain a bit why I like them, and neo-banks in general. And yes, I mention referral because OP is looking for saving fees on transfers, and that is a way to save more. Note I have **not** provided any referral link or code !

Comment: @DanubianSailor Yes, but SWIFT is very much like wire transfer. I doesn't do anything special if you use SWIFT between the same bank in different countries, and it certainly doesn't reduce the fees, which OP is mentioning several times

Answer (score 2):

Not without special programs that the bank offers.

What you think of as "bank transfer" relies on (electronic) settlement protocols individual countries may set up to facilitate electronic transfer of money between accounts of domestic banks. They typically connect to the central supervisory authority (ie. often the central bank) somehow and that's where the technical movement of money is sorted out.

When crossing international boundaries, those domestic systems no longer apply and banks need to use for example the Bank of International Settlements to facilitate movement of money. As money crosses jurisdictions, there is bound to be more regulatory checks and fraud-prevention checks. And to do that, there will be cost. And that is what the "wire transfer" you think of is nowadays.

The same applies to "international" banks that keep the same brand name, some management structure but operate as separate entities across jurisdictions when it comes to regular banking. (ie. obviously, things like trading or investment 'banking' would be different.)

Thus, the answer to your second question is simply: absent of special circumstances, wire transfer is the best.

You pay for actual services. And you should be able to find banks that offer a fixed (relatively trivial, compared to buying a house) fee as opposed to percentage fee for wire transfer.

---

EDIT:

Special circumstances can include:

- a local bank in your area having special arrangement with another bank in your destination area that facilitate direct settlement -- thus reducing the cost they need to charge to you
- your current area and destination area being in a wider jurisdiction such as the Eurozone
- your current area and destination area being covered by a (trading) broker -- again, same entity only, not brand

These circumstances mean that it may be worth your time investigating alternatives. But alternatives are still not guaranteed. You can try Googling for local banks that advertise international transfer of money. If you don't find quick results, that means those special circumstances in the background don't apply to you; so just go with wire.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin this answer is particularly informative

Answer (score 1):

Checks/Cheques are another (slower) option.

We keep a USD account in the international bank where we can convert the funds to USD, then have the bank mail us a check from the USD funds.  The down side is that my local bank puts a month hold on the funds.  There is a fee if we use certified mail, but not if using regular mail.  You would have to verify with your local bank that they would accept a check like this from the other country (either in the foreign currency or USD).

We used to do the international banking free transfer thing.  The problem was that both the US and international bank charged monthly fees, whereas my local bank does not.  I couldn't justify keeping that monthly fee charging US bank account open just to transfer money, especially since they don't have any branches in my state.  We just didn't transfer funds that frequently to justify the cost of keeping another account open.

Comment: Many banks will charge an arm and a leg when you deposit a foreign check, as well as outrageous currency exchange fees/rates.

Comment: Yes, banks are great at tacking on fees.  Brokerage accounts might give better exchange rates.  If it participates in the NSCC's ACAT system, you can transfer the entire account to a brokerage in the US if they are traded on the NYSE.

Answer (score 1):

The Post Office offers this service. Our local Post Office is often visited by foreign workers paying money into their accounts, which their families can then access at the other end.

Having said that, this is inside Eurasia. The rules may be different depending how far you want to go. But it's worth asking at your local post office.

Comment: Yes, I believe most Post Offices offer this service through Western Union, which has higher fees, and low limit on the amount that can be transferred.